# When debian bugfix will appear on my system?

Tags: debian, apt, npm

On my Debian 10 I've ran into same problem with npm as many people before:

```
npm does not support Node.js v10.15.2
```

Searching for the fix I've found that the bug was fixed in debian:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=904422

But I have latest version of npm package from debian apt and it is still 5.8.0. Can someone explain if and when the bugfix will be in debian stable repo? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bug was fixed in version 6.13.4+ds-1, and that particular version (or any later version) won’t ever be added to Debian 10. You could ask for a backport to `buster-backports`, I’m not sure how difficult it would be...

One of the replies to the bug report includes a patch for 5.8.0, you could apply that locally:

```
sudo sed -i "s/ver: '9'.*/&,/;/ver: '9'/a{ver: '10', min: '10.0.0'}" /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Strange that the bugfix will never apper in Debian 10.

Comment: It’s not considered severe enough for a fix in the stable distribution.